# Angular ng-click event not firing for dialog box button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, button, dialog

I am creating a dialog pop up on my website, and for some reason when I click a button that is supposed to fire an event and close the dialog, the dialog is not being closed. My javascript code for the button looks like this...

```
$scope.alert = function () {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2 - (550 * .5) + "px");
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "header";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "body";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button ng-click="cancelAlert()">Cancel</button>   <button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>';
}

$scope.cancelAlert = function () {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
}

$scope.continueAlert = function () {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

I am going to make the Continue event do something different in the future, but as of now either button should get rid of the dialog...

When I call the alert it looks like this in my javascript code...

```
    if (raiseAlert) {
        $scope.alert();
    }
```

And my html looks like this...

```
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
    <div>
        <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
        <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
        <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS for the alert looks like this (I don't know if this is pertinent at all, but problems in CSS can mess other stuff up sometimes)...

```
#dialogoverlay{
display: none;
opacity: .8;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: #FFF;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;

}
#dialogbox{
display: none;
position: fixed;
background: #000;
border-radius:7px;
width: 550px;
z-index: 10;
}

#dialogbox > div{background: #FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody {
    background: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot {
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Why aren't the `cancelAlert()` or `continueAlert()` functions being called and closing out of the dialog like they should?

UPDATE:

I have changed the code to now look like this...

```
    var html = $('<button ng-click = "cancelAlert()" > Cancel</button > <button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>');
    var div = $compile(html);
    var content = div($scope);
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "header";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "body";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = content;
```

And the result is that this produces html text that looks like the following...

```
[[object HTMLButtonElement], [object Text], [object HTMLButtonElement]]
```

How do I convert this HTML text into the actual buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with  **$compile** on controller for append innerhtml

```
app.controller("cntrl", ['$scope','$compile',
function ($scope,$compile) {

$scope.alert = function () {
var html = angular.element('<button ng-click="cancelAlert()"> Cancel</button ><button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>');
var div = $compile(html);
var content = div($scope);
     angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogboxfoot')).append(content[0].outerHTML);
     angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogboxfoot')).append(content[1].outerHTML);
}
```

For example

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl",  ['$scope','$compile',
  function ($scope,$compile){
  $scope.alert = function () {
  var html = angular.element('<button ng-click="cancelAlert()"> Cancel</button ><button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>');
    var div = $compile(html);
    var content = div($scope);
 document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "header";
 document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "body";
 angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogboxfoot')).append(content[0].outerHTML);
 angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogboxfoot')).append(content[1].outerHTML);
}
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox" ng-init="alert()">
    <div>
        <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
        <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
        <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
```

Hop's that help

Comment: I tried inserting document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML into where you said document.body in your response, but what appeared in the dialog box was only the text [[object HTMLButtonElement], [object Text], [object HTMLButtonElement]]

Comment: Let's check it with updated answer. 
I wish this answer will be helpful for you :)

Comment: Now the button appears, but it still does not do anything when I click it

Comment: Ok I got it to work! Partially, at least. I have what you suggested, except I didn't use .outerHTML after content[0] and content[1].  When I used it with outerHTML, the cancel button appeared but did not respond properly to clicking.  The only strange thing now is that the Continue button does not appear for some reason.

Comment: Ok, solved it. The button objects come in a list of html objects (hence why we access content[0]). The space listed in between the two buttons is listed as another object, so accessing content[1] just accesses the space in between the buttons. content[2] is what actually contains the second button. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add, `ng-click` dynamically like this.
You have to use, `$compile()` to make it work.

```
divtoappend.append($compile('<button ng-click="cancelAlert()">Cancel</button>   <button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>')($scope));
```

In your case you have to append button to `div` with id `dialogboxfoot`. So you can do something like this:

`var el = document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot');`

```
el.append($compile(divtoappend.append($compile('<button ng-click="cancelAlert()">Cancel</button>   <button ng-click="continueAlert()">Continue</button>')($scope));
```

To use `$compile` you have to inject that in the controller like `$scope`, to make it available to the controller.